# Mirror image of the neg symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a mirror symbol for the `$\neg$` symbol, or a symbol like `$\vdash$` without the bottom part of the vertical line? I couldn't find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\llcorner` from `amsmath` or `\niv` from `nath`, amongst others. Just [look in the usual places](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol).

Answer (score 2):

If you want something with the exact same proportions, you could rotate the original symbol

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rotatedneg}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath\neg}}
\begin{document}
\[
\neg \rotatedneg \vdash
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: what about vdash without the bottom part, instead of neg which removes the upper part?

Comment: @kloop sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I have edited my answer.